# relative and absolute in CSS, not working as expected

Tags: html, css, position

I'm following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tlb4tv4mC4&t=956s as a noob. Typed exactly as instructed, no typos (that I can see). Trying to make a memory match game.

Currently at this stage:

[image]

```
body{
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
background-color: blue; }

section {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 8rem);
grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 8rem);
grid-gap: 2rem;}



.face,
.back {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%; }


.back {
background: green;}
```

I'm now trying to make the back of the card (the green), lay over the images of album covers.

In the tutorial, Position absolute and relative are used, and no problems are discovered, however this happens to mine. It should be the same grid, but green, rather than album covers.

[image]

```
body{
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
background-color: blue;}

section {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 8rem);
grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 8rem);
grid-gap: 2rem }

.card {
position: relative}

.face,
.back {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
position: absolute;}


.back {
background: green;}
```

I've tried: setting parent as a grid - and child as column: 1, row: 1. Doesn't work. I've tried adding top and left to position, doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Also included is HTML and JS.

Many thanks,

[image: JS]

[image]

```
     // Select some elements
const section = document.querySelector('section');
const playerLivesCount = document.querySelector('span');
const playerLives = 6;

//Link text

playerLivesCount.textContent = playerLives;

//Generate the date
const getData = () => [
    {imgSrc:"./images/beatles.jpeg", name: "beatles" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/blink182.jpeg", name: "blink 182" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/fkatwigs.jpeg", name: "fka twigs" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/fleetwood.jpeg", name: "fleetwoodMac" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/joy-division.jpeg", name: "joy-division" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/ledzep.jpeg", name: "led zepplin" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/metallica.jpeg", name: "metallica" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/pinkfloyd.jpeg", name: "pink floyd" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/beatles.jpeg", name: "beatles" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/blink182.jpeg", name: "blink 182" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/fkatwigs.jpeg", name: "fka twigs" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/fleetwood.jpeg", name: "fleetwoodMac" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/joy-division.jpeg", name: "joy-division" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/ledzep.jpeg", name: "led zepplin" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/metallica.jpeg", name: "metallica" },
    {imgSrc:"./images/pinkfloyd.jpeg", name: "pink floyd" },
];

//randomise

const randomise = () => {
    const cardData = getData();
    cardData.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    return cardData;
    };


//Generate HTML
const cardGenerator = () => {
    const cardData = randomise();

    cardData.forEach((item) => {
        const card = document.createElement("div");
        const face = document.createElement("img");
        const back = document.createElement("div");
        card.classlist = "card";
        face.classList = "face";
        back.classList = "back";
    
    face.src= item.imgSrc
   //Attach card to section
   section.appendChild(card);
   card.appendChild(face);
   card.appendChild(back);

    });

     

};

cardGenerator();


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    <script src ="./app.js" defer></script>
    <title>Memory Game</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Lives: <span class="playerLivesCount"></span> </h1>
    <section></section>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please paste your code into the question, instead of a screenshot.

Comment: It is hard to say, how the output HTML code is generated. Make sure `.face` and `.back` is inside a `.card`. Then position relative "catch" position absolute :)